# Phonegap 4.2.0 doesn't produce APK

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to compile a simple Hello World phonegap application.

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
phonegap cordova platform add android
```

I have JAVA installed, and Android SDK installed so everything works up until this point.

I then try to produce simple APK, by running

```
phonegap build android
```

according to documentation it should appear in `platform/android/bin`
but it just doesn't, I've tried various flags, like `--release` etc, but nothing helps.
The output I get when building:

```
$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android'
```

when building for `FirefoxOS` for example, - I get `package.zip` in `bin` folder, but nothing for Android...

Answer (score 2):

When using cordova instead of phonegap, the path of the apk generated is displayed at the end. Maybe should you run cordova directly instead of phonegap?

Anyway, since about version 3.6, apks are no more generated in platform/android/bin but instead in platforms/android/ant-build.

Comment: ok, turns out, I had to install ANT, which is never documented by phonegap

Comment: actually it's documented (maybe not clearly enough) in phonegap's android platform guide : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide